# HDIO_GETGEO and HDIO_GET_IDENTITY in Linux using C++

Tags: c++, linux, ioctl

Can anyone explain the core difference between `HDIO_GETGEO` and `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY`. From `Linux` documentation I know that the former is for `getting device geometry` and the latter for `getting IDE identification info`.

Which `HDIO_ ioctl call` should I use to get the no. of sectors and bytes per sector of my hard disk in Linux??